# Angular select is not updating

Tags: angularjs, rest, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have problem with select in angular.

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="vm.targetClassName" ng-options="item for item in vm.classList">
</select>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
vm.targetClassName = 'b';
generalResources.getClasses().then(setClasses);
function setClasses(classes) {
    vm.classList = classes.value;
}
```

After this block of code `vm.classList` is containing array of Strings, for example `['a', 'b', 'c']`

What I expect is that select has three options, and the `'b'` is selected however I only got select with three options, but nothing is selected.

I checked these values with AngularJS Inspector and it clearly shows that `vm.classList` is `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `vm.targetClassName` is `'b'`;

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It seems to be working for me, take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rCOv2FPdjVP5ksFYw2nU?p=preview). Could you please reproduce the issue here, If I'm missing anything?

Comment: Everything is fine as long as vm.classList is not response from backend.

Comment: check plunker once again.. I updated it to load values lately.. it doesn't made any effect.. it seems to be working fine for me..

Comment: Yes, It is working in your example, but in my project it is not - only in case of geting data from backend

Comment: I also tried to reproduce your example with timeout and it is also not working in project. Meybe I should also mention that the following code is inside directive and it's opened by dialog service

Comment: May be your angular version is different, I;m using latest one

Comment: I have to use angular 1.3, and I can't change it for any newer version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue isn't reproducible with Angular current version 1.6.3. It seems like Angular 1.3 specific issue. Though you could fix this issue by using `track by` on `ng-options` directive

```
<select ng-model="vm.targetClassName" 
   ng-options="item for item in vm.classList track by item">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/R5bFpNJXtFlFHGDGNo3O?p=preview)